# stacking histograms in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The stacking is not working correctly. This is what I get:

[image]

This might be a problem of different bins, but even restricting them is not working (slightly related questions about common bins are [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144835/superposing-histogram-and-barplot-with-transparency), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214784/custom-column-intervals-in-a-pgfplots-histogram), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168051/create-a-stacked-histogram-with-tikz). Yet, they have not been helpful).

This is my code from above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar stacked,normalsize,width=10cm,enlargelimits=0,bar width=0.6cm,
            ytick={0,200,400,600,800,1000},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xtick={0,20,...,100},
            ]
            \addplot+[hist={bins=25,data min=-2,data max=102}] table [x,y index=0] {w1.csv};
            \addplot+[hist={bins=25,data min=-2,data max=102}] table [x,y index=0] {w2.csv};
            \addplot+[hist={bins=25,data min=-2,data max=102}] table [x,y index=0] {w3.csv};
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My data (numbers) comes from three files, each with one column. Files are very large. Therefore, I will use a small example that shows the problem clearly.

This is the example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{w.csv}
1.4
1.1
2.2
3.3
4.1
4.5
6.1
6.6
6.6
7.4
8.1
8.3
9.1
9.1
9.1
\end{filecontents} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,xtick={0,1,...,10},ytick={0,1,...,6}]
        \addplot+[hist={bins=10,data min=0,data max=10}] table [x,y index=0] {w.csv};
        \addplot+[hist={bins=10,data min=0,data max=10}] table [x,y index=0] {w.csv};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Notice that, for simplicity, I'm using the **same file**. In consequence, the pattern of stacked histograms should be trivial. Yet, this is the output:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/102/). Updating to version 1.13 of `pgfplots` does not solve the issue.

Comment: Version 1.17 still does not solve the issue. It remains [open](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/102)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found no other thread with this topic.
As this is not resolved in pgfplots 1.15 my solution was to simply "stack" the files myself, e.g.

```
data-1.txt = [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]
data-2.txt = [ 1 3 3 4 5 ]
data-1-and-2.txt = [ 1 2 3 4 5 1 3 3 4 5 ]
```

then plot data-1-and-2.txt first and data-1.txt after that and omit

```
ybar stacked
```

in the axis environment

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xtick={0,1,...,10},ytick={0,1,...,6}]
    \addplot+[hist={bins=10,data min=0,data max=10}] table [x,y index=0]  {data-1-and-2.txt};
    \addplot+[hist={bins=10,data min=0,data max=10}] table [x,y index=0] {data-1.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add a minimal  running code with preamble, `\documentclass` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Yes, and add a picture of the result please.